# How do I get LWP using Linux glibc?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I developed a process with some threads on a Linux machine (Ubuntu). I'd like to know how can i get LWP from each thread (using a glibc function), once the PID and PPID are always the same for all the threads of the process.

```
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2588  2587  2588  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:07 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2589  2   11 00:05 ?        00:23:17 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2590  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2591  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:03 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2592  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2593  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2594  0   11 00:05 ?        00:05:05 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2595  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2596  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:37 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2597  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
root      2588  2587  2601  0   11 00:05 ?        00:00:00 ./testsrv
```

Comment: LWP stand for Light Weight Process : means a thread. I guess you try to get the thread ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use gettid() from man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>       gettid()  returns  the  caller's thread ID (TID).  In a single-threaded
>       process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned  by
>       getpid(2)).  In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID,
>       but each one has a unique TID.  For further details, see the discussion
>       of CLONE_THREAD in clone(2).
>
> RETURN VALUE
>       On success, returns the thread ID of the calling process.

Comment: Unfortunately i got an error message while trying gettid(): undefined reference to `gettid'. After some hours of researching i found and tested a multiplatform solution that really works: PlatformThreadId  GetCurrentThreadId(void)
   {
       #if defined(__APPLE__)
       return mach_thread_self();
       #elif defined(_LINUX)
       #ifdef __NR_gettid
       return syscall(__NR_gettid);
       #else
       return (getpid());
       #endif
       #endif
   }

Comment: the same from the man page:
       #define _GNU_SOURCE
       #include <unistd.h>
       #include <sys/syscall.h>
       #include <sys/types.h>

       int
       main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           pid_t tid;

           tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
       }